# Getting mvc 3 exception: The controller for path '/GMIS/ie-css3.htc' was not found or does not implement IController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, logging, exception, log4net

The application seems to run fine? But I keep seeing these exceptions in my log:

```
2013-03-11 11:32:46,736 [30] DEBUG COPSGMIS.Logging.GMISLogging - Executing controller: Home, action: Index
2013-03-11 11:32:48,934 [30] ERROR COPSGMIS.MvcApplication - GMIS Exception
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/GMIS/ie-css3.htc' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the  `ie-css3.htc` to the content folder.

Comment: when I place it in Content its geos: http://www.example.com/GMIS/content/ie-css3.htc? Where should it be placed to go http://www.example.com/GMIS/ie-css3.htc

Comment: Why don't you want to place it in the contents folder and reference it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Add this line

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("GMIS/ie-css3.htc");
```

above your call where you MapRoute

Comment: Added the line in RegisterRoutes(..) in the global, still not suppressing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I overlooked it..in my style sheet I had the following:

```
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
```

it needed to be:

```
behavior: url(../Content/ie-css3.htc);
```